# msp430 (telosb) adc driver for mq5 sensor in contiki

Tags: driver, sensors, msp430, contiki, adc

I am trying to connect MQ5 sensor to a Telosb and read the values, and i am using contiki os.
My problem now is:
I know that i need an ADC driver in contiki os, but i do not know how to do it or from where to start ?
Can anyone guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

The ADC driver for TelosB is already implemented in Contiki, you can find it in file `sky-sensors.c` and `sky-sensors.h` in `contiki/platforms/sky`.

See `light-sensor.c` and `temperature-sensor.c` for examples of sensor drivers that use this "sky_sensor" API. Basically you need to select which ADC input channel to use and what reference voltage to use, the rest is trivial: call `sky_sensors_configure` function and read from the right memory location mapped to an ADC input port. For example, by reading `ADC12MEM4` you can access the ADC channel 4.

Comment: I find it puzzling that someone comes here to post a question and then completely avoids following up on the responses.